# How to Listening or preventing display shutdown menu in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-powermanager

I want to prevent opening shutdown menu in android  and  knows maybe isn't possible. I my solution I want prevent shutdown android device by android menu

I have two ideas :

1. preventing opening shutdown menu
2. listening shutdown menu is open and inflate a layout

Any code for checking Power key not work like this in new android version :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
  int keyPressed = event.getKeyCode();
  if(keyPressed==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER){
    Log.d("###","Power button long click");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked: "+keyPressed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;}
  else
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Do you have any idea for this problem because my app isn't system app(non root device)?

Comment: "I want prevent shutdown android device by android menu" -- if that is possible, it is a significant security flaw.

Comment: Do you have any solution ?